# Convert List<Map<String, Object>> to string json

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a following method which creates list of map and populates it with product code and quantity:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> createListOfMap(int count) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, count).forEach(i -> {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("productCode", TEST_PRODUCT_CODE_PREFIX + (i + 1));
        map.put("quantity", i + 1);
        list.add(map);
    });
    return list;
}
```

And I want to convert this list of map into string as JSON:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = createProductCodes(count);
 String listAsString = String.join(", ", listOfMap); // Cannot resolve method 'join(String, List<Map<String, Object>>)'
 String stringAsJSON = "[" + listAsString + "]";
```

So issue is that "Cannot resolve method 'join(String, List<Map<String, Object>>)'" like i commented out:

I did something similar with List, but it's simpler and I could use String.join:

```
private List<String> createProductCodes(int count) {
    return IntStream.range(0, count)
        .mapToObj(i -> TEST_PRODUCT_CODE_PREFIX + (i + 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

List<String> productCodes = createProductCodes(count);
String listAsString = String.join(", ", productCodes);
String stringAsJSON = "[" + listAsString + "]";
```

So my question is there anything like `String.join(", ", productCodes)` but that would `List<Map<String, Object>>`?

Comment: I believe `Gson gson = new Gson(); gson.toJson(list)` is one way to go. Anything else without using gson from google ?

Comment: Java does not have functionality for dealing with json included in the jdk. Your options are 3rd party libraries - gson, jackson, and many more. Unless you want to implement your own library for working with json, you will have to pick one.